# How to connect one barcode scanner to multiple machines using USB & serial interfaces

Tags: networking, usb, serial-port, com, barcode-scanner

Is it is possible to connect one barcode scanner to two machines to receive the same signal at the same time?  In this case, either:

- barcode scanner to USB and serial port, or
- barcode scanner to USB and USB

Is it possible? If so, can it be accomplished using standard, off-the-shelf adapters or would custom hardware be required?

Comment: Can you clarify "at the same time"?  Must it be simultaneous, or can it simply be that both machines get it at nearly the same time?  What's the actual requirement you need to accomplish?  What is the model of the scanner?  What is the output port of the scanner (both USB and serial)?  If it contains both, can the scanner output to both or do you need to select one?  Would it be acceptable for one machine to get the input and then share it with the other machine if that happened at almost the same time and the second machine got everything the first machine got from the scanner?  (cont'd)

Comment: Typically, there is some handshaking between a device like a scanner and a computer; it isn't very reliable to just stream data into the ether and hope to capture it completely and without error.  That handshaking requires some complexity (which the scanner may not support) If you are just splitting the signal and sending it in two directions.

Comment: @fixer1234 it really doesnt matter it can be simultaneous or nearly at the same time. my first tought is to write a program in the PC to receive the data and then stream it to the Serial Port. 
The output of the scanner is USB i dont have any models ATM

Comment: If the scanner is USB, I don't think you could simply use a splitter to connect it to two computers.  But it should be straightforward to connect the scanner to one machine and have that one resent to data to the second machine.  That could be over a network connection, no need to mess with serial ports (unless they are ancient computers, they won't even have serial ports).  In fact, both computers don't need to process the raw scanner data.  The first computer can translate the data to final form and then send that to the second computer.

Comment: but if it is a Scanner with Serial port we can just use a splitter ? like connecting just the TX Pin to the RX ? 
Also transmitting data over network connection you mean TCP/IP ?

Comment: So, does the scanner send the serial or USB data? If it is the first one after all, then there is even no need in the additional hardware. Just create an additional virtual serial port and send data over the network to another machine. It can be done with [serial over ethernet connector](https://www.serial-over-ethernet.com/) for instance. COM1 -> COM2 (local PC); COM1 -> COM3 (remote PC, data sent over network).

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy with a serial line, just connect the output pin of the scanner to the input pin of each of the machines. This assumes that the scanner just sends data and doesn't need to receive anything.
I don't know whether adapters for this exist, but it would be simple to make one yourself, or have someone do it who has experience with a soldering iron.

For USB the protocol is much more complicated, and such a simple solution would not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer im not a hardware expert and the option to use a Y cable with two serials is available. the pins are [Those?](https://www.stratusengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/RS232-9-pin-pinout-explained.jpg) 
So i should just connect the Pin 3 from the scanner to the Pin 2 of both devices and it will work?